# bootstrap datepicker not localizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've used bootstrap datepicker on my rails application. I've added the `bootstrap-datepicker.js` and `bootstrap-datepicker.de.js` to my **app/assets/javascripts** folder. 
On my view page I've added the following code:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker form-control"/>

<script>
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
            language:'de',
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            startDate: '-3d'
        });
</script>
```

The problem is that, datepicker always shows the default(English) Month,Day name instead of showing the Month and Day names in German. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you require `bootstrap-datepicker.de.js` somewhere? For example in `application.js`: `require bootstrap-datepicker.de`, or with `javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-datepicker.de.js"` in some view.

Comment: @sjaime, Yes I've required the bootstrap-datepicker.de.js in my application.js file.

Comment: Some more tips to help debugging: if you open dev tools or Firebug console and load the page, do you happen to see any error related to the datepicker? And finally, do you use `$('.datepicker').datepicker` elsewhere in your code that might be overriding the language setting?

Answer (score 1):

locales/

```
<script src="locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are probably missing `<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.de.js></script>` on your html file.